# Mapping xmltype oracle with entity framework 6 code first annotations

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, xmltype

I try use code first with a column of xmltype

---

In my db:

TIPOS_GRIFOS

ID_TIPOS_GRIFOS : NUMBER(38,0)

DESC_TIPOS_GRIFOS : VARCHAR2(250 BYTE)

CONFIG : XMLTYPE

---

In my code:

```
[Table("TIPOS_GRIFOS")]
public class TiposGrifos : BaseEntity
{
    [Column("ID_TIPOS_GRIFOS"), Key]
    public int IdTiposGrifos { get; set;}

    [Column("DESC_TIPOS_GRIFOS")]
    public string DescTiposGrifos
    { get; set; }

    [Column("CONFIG")]
    public string Config
    { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public XElement xmlData
    {
        get { return XElement.Parse(Config); }
        set { Config = value.ToString(); }
    }}
```

I can execute:

```
   var tiposGrifo = repository.GetById(1);
   tiposGrifo.xmlData = template;
```

And this object is fine, with data imported correctly from the db. But when I try context.SaveChanges (), it throw ORA-932 exception.

Thanks.

PD: I tried with

```
   [Column(TypeName="xml")]
   public string Config { get; set; }
```

and that did not work.

---

## UPDATE

I found the problem:

**An "ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got NCLOB" error will be encountered when trying to bind a string that is equal to or greater than 2,000 characters in length to an XMLType column or parameter. [Bug 12630958]**

I've tried inserting a small xml (less than 2000 characters), and my code works perfectly. But I need to be able to insert larger xml... Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update :**

This is Oracle data provider's Known Issue.So you have to wait until they'll fix this issue.

> 6. An "ORA-00932 : inconsistent datatypes" error can be encountered if a string of 2,000 or more characters, or a byte  array with 4,000
>      bytes or more in length, is bound in a WHERE clause of a LINQ/ESQL
>      query. The same error can be  encountered if an entity property that
>      maps to a BLOB, CLOB, NCLOB, LONG, LONG RAW, XMLTYPE column is used in
>      a WHERE  clause of a LINQ/ESQL query.

You can read about it under the [**Entity Framework Tips, Limitations, and Known Issues**](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/odpnet-ef-nuget-12102400-2718789.txt) section on this doc.

**Original Post :**

You can try it with **Fluent API** as shown below.

```
public String Config { get; set; }

public XElement xmlData
{
    get { return XElement.Parse(Config); }
    set { Config = value.ToString(); }
}

public partial class XmlEntityMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<XmlEntity>
{
    public FilterMap()
    {
        this.Property(c => c.Config).HasColumnType("xml");
        this.Ignore(c => c.xmlData);
    }
}
```

Comment: I also tried that, but it didn't work. Thank you anyway.

Comment: please see the **Update**.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try another way to save the data.